# Django Elastic Search: AttributeError: type object 'PostDocument' has no attribute 'Django'

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am very new in elasetic search in django...
When i run this command, `python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild`
 it fires me this error: I am not getting whats wrong with it

```
File "/home/pyking/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/registries.py", line 39, in register_document
    django_meta = getattr(document, 'Django')
AttributeError: type object 'PostDocument' has no attribute 'Django'
```

This is my `documents.py`

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index
from blog2.models import Article

posts = Index('articles')

@posts.doc_type
class PostDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

        fields = [
            'alias',
            'author',
            'title',
            'body',
            'category',
        ]
```

and this is my models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am not getting whats wrong with my code, even it is not firing me my code problem, it is firing me some odd error..

Comment: FIrst of all you should use `Document` class to declare documents instead of `DocType`, because mapping type (i.e DocType) is deprecated in APIs in ES 7.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not `Meta` class, it should be `Django` class which you should create and tell model, fields and other config related to this document and it's model.
Please see documentation and it's sample example.
https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl#quickstart

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Index
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from blog2.models import Article

posts = Index('articles')

@registry.register_document
@posts.document
class PostDocument(Document):
    class Django:
        model = Article

        fields = [
            'alias',
            'author',
            'title',
            'body',
            'category',
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks bro, you made my day

Comment: Most welcome. To keep you away from these issue, better keep eye on details of examples.

Comment: Thanks again dude, you are great

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. They have an error in docs that says META instead of Django

Comment: Thank you! You save my time!!)

Comment: what if I don't use a django model, can this class be empty?